# Passing data from parent class to JDialog box

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jdialog

How to pass data from a different class or parent class to a JDialog box? I tried using a setter and a getter but it still returns *null*. Help?

Comment: It would be more like, how would the JDialog box access that data or the value from the Frame/different/parent class

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.